# Google crawling mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-search-console

I currently have a WordPress site linked to it is a separate database holding product information that is required for the search page I have created.

I have created a sitemaps using SOFTplus GSiteCrawler. This creates a site map showing all the pages generated from the data base, I have submitted these to webmaster.

Every page from the separate database is giving a response 404 to webmaster although when you click on the url in the errors listing it takes you to a perfectly normal page on problems.

This is what the extension looks like

item_detail.php?make=Sony&model=CPD-G500+G&partno=&id=81583

Thank you

Hope this is not to confusing

Comment: Are you serving 404 header? If you load the page does it have a 200 status code? Is the date when the error was found much older than the current date?

Comment: Using a checker the result is HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found, Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT

Comment: So it sounds like you are serving 404 headers. If you open the network tab and load the page do you see it as a 404? What checker did you use, does it have a graphical representation of the page? You could try it on webpagetest.org

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. For anyone in the future looking for an answer:

I added the following to my htaccess and pages are now returning 200

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /
```